# How to schedule cron job to run everyday at 3 am in NiFi

Tags: cron, apache-nifi, minify, crontrigger

I have a flow that fetches data from Presto and does some ETL and pushes back the CSV file to the s3 bucket. My flow is as follows:

```
**QueryDatabaseTable -> convertRecord -> RouteText -> puts3Object**
```

I know we can achieve this with cron job scheduling feature. The idea is to have new files ingested every morning in the s3 bucket.

what will be the cron syntax?? I tried `0 0 3 1/1 * ? *` but it doesn't seem to run at 3 am every day. Any reason why?

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go to the setting of QueryDatabaseTable processor, scheduling, cron and put the cron value to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Lamanus What will be the right syntax, the one I am trying doesn't seem to work. Can you help?

Comment: `0 0 3 * * ?` maybe?

Comment: Why is this question a "-1"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nifi uses `quartz cron` for syntax, you can create/test your cron expressions in this [link](http://www.cronmaker.com/?2).

To schedule at `3AM` everyday use the below cron expression:

`Right Click on QuerydatabaseTable -> configure -> Scheduling tab -> Scheduling Strategy(choose) CRON driven!`

```
0 0 3 1/1 * ? *
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Generator to easily create your cron jobs compatible with Nifi. (quartz cron)

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Example :

```
0 0 0 1/1 * ? *

At 00:00:00am, every day starting on the 1st, every month
```

[image]